# Python/Unix os.system: Can anyone tell me why this piece of code using awk does not work when executed with os.system?

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, os.system

I have been working with this piece of code for some time in Unix systems and it works just fine while running on a normal command line.  However, for the sake of a project and learning how to execute Unix commands through Python, I am trying to run it using the os.system() command in Python.

Overall data structure has 5 columns and 1500 rows and the goal is to replace values greater than 2.706 in column 4 ($4) and then proceed to save them into file2.txt while keeping all other values in the file the same.

```
os.system("awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4>=2.706)? -999 : $4}' file1.txt > file2.txt")
```

From this code, I receive the message *Invalid syntax* after attempting the execution from a python script.

As I am new to Python, I believe I must just missing something in the syntax from that side of the code, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

A new attempt with the same code, but using the subprocess module instead of os.system:

```
arg1 = "awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4>=2.7059553)\? -999 \: $4}' phenotypes.txt > replacetest.txt"
subprocess.run(arg1, shell=TRUE)
```

This code also gives the *Invalid syntax* response to the creation of the arg1 command.

(Code is being run in Python 2.7.5 on Linux2.)

Comment: You should use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) with `shell=True`.

Comment: Hello there and thanks for the help! Would you be able to assist me with the syntax of the subprocess module? I have looked over the documentation, and attempted to use it as suggested with the following code: _arg1 = "awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4>=2.7059553)\? -999 \: $4}' phenotypes.txt > replacetest.txt"_ then _subprocess.run(arg1, shell=TRUE)_ but to no avail! I'm afraid my ignorance is showing ^^'

Comment: Please add all code to the question itself. In the comments it is unreadable.

Comment: sure thing, I have done so!

Comment: You should give the arguments to the `subprocess.run()` command as a list without additional quotation marks and as raw strings is needed. Try: `arg1 = ['awk', r'{print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4>=2.7059553)\? -999 \: $4}', 'phenotypes.txt', '>', 'replacetest.txt']`

Comment: With Python 3.6.5 on a Linux machine, I was able to run `os.system("awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4>=2.706)? -999 : $4}' file1.txt > file2.txt")` in a script without error as well as `arg1 = "awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4>=2.7059553)? -999 : $4}' phenotypes.txt > replacetest.txt"` (note: I removed the backslashes). Perhaps the issue is your environment setup or your python script?

Comment: It could very well be that.  I've tried your suggestion again @KlausD. but to no avail for me. The system I work on is one given to me through a cluster system, so I cannot speak well to the environment, but I'll keep trying and see if anything works!

Comment: as a note, I did add the system I am working on in the question description above. Also, thank you both for your comments, they have at least helped me learn more about this new language!